# navigating text file searches in python

Tags: python, search, input, text-files, nltk

here is sample of the text file I am working with:

```
<Opera>

Tristan/NNP
and/CC
Isolde/NNP
and/CC
the/DT
fatalistic/NN
horns/VBZ
The/DT
passionate/JJ
violins/NN
And/CC
ominous/JJ
clarinet/NN
;/:
```

The capital letters after the forward slashes are weird tags. I want to be able to search the file for something like `"NNP,CC,NNP"` and have the program return for this segment `"Tristan and Isolde"`, the three words in a row that match those three tags in a row.

The problem I am having is I want the search string to be user inputed so it will always be different.
I can read the file and find one match but I do not know how to count backwards from that point to print the first word or how to find whether the next tag matches.

Comment: How big is the file?  (From an earlier post one of your files was too large to keep multiple copies of it in memory.)  Are there carriage returns or is it all one big horizontal line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your source text was possibly produced by [Natural Language Toolkit (nltk)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nltk&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.nltk.org/&ei=lYEtT5S3D-rc0QHGtuHdCg&usg=AFQjCNFAaOWlHZHy3sIDfIX4Hsc4O8s_aw).

Using nltk, you could tokenize the text, split the token into (word, part_of_speech) tuples, and iterate through ngrams to find those that match the pattern:

```
import nltk
pattern = 'NNP,CC,NNP'
pattern = [pat.strip() for pat in pattern.split(',')]
text = '''Tristan/NNP and/CC Isolde/NNP and/CC the/DT fatalistic/NN horns/VBZ
          The/DT passionate/JJ violins/NN And/CC ominous/JJ clarinet/NN ;/:'''
tagged_token = [nltk.tag.str2tuple(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text)]
for ngram in nltk.ingrams(tagged_token,len(pattern)):
    if all(gram[1] == pat for gram,pat in zip(ngram,pattern)):
        print(' '.join(word for word, pos in ngram))
```

yields

```
Tristan and Isolde
```

---

Related link:

- [Categorizing and Tagging Words](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html) (chapter 5 of the NLTK book)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re 
>>> s = "Tristan/NNP and/CC Isolde/NNP and/CC the/DT fatalistic/NN horns/VBZ The/DT passionate/JJ violins/NN And/CC ominous/JJ clarinet/NN ;/:"
>>> re.findall("(\w+)/NNP (\w+)/CC (\w+)/NNP", s)
[('Tristan', 'and', 'Isolde')]
```

Similarly, you can do what you need.

EDIT: More generalized.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = 'NNP,CC,NNP'
>>> pattern = pattern.split(",")
>>> p = ""
>>> for i in pattern:
...     p = p + r"(\w+)/"+i+ r"\n"
>>> f = open("yourfile", "r")
>>> s = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> found = re.findall(p, s, re.MULTILINE)
>>> found #Saved in found
[('Tristan', 'and', 'Isolde')]
>>> found_str = " ".join(found[0]) #Converted to string
>>> f = open("written.txt", "w")
>>> f.write(found_str)
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a couple of questions about this method. Can I call a text file instead of s? Also, where does re.findall return whatever it has found? Can that be written out to a text file as well. Thanks again, it is hard to learn this stuff on your own.

Comment: Thanks, your answer has certainly helped. I am reading up on regular expressions but it is quite complicated. I need to find one more tag for each match. I need to find whatever is inside and xml tag. So when I find a match I want to look ahead until I find the <name> tag and print whatever is inside the brackets. Can I do this with RE as well?

Comment: Don't use RE for parsing XML. @unutbu had the most accurate answer, btw.

Comment: Its not really XML it is just a tag in the text file. If I find Tristan and Isolde I need to know what is in the tag that comes before it. Can I do that use RE?

Answer (score 1):

Build a regular expression dynamically from a list of tags you want to search:

```
text = ("Tristan/NNP and/CC Isolde/NNP and/CC the/DT fatalistic/NN horns/VBZ "
    "The/DT passionate/JJ violins/NN And/CC ominous/JJ clarinet/NN")

tags = ["NNP", "CC", "NNP"]
tags_pattern = r"\b" + r"\s+".join(r"(\w+)/{0}".format(tag) for tag in tags) + r"\b"
# gives you r"\b(\w+)/NNP\s+(\w+)/CC\s+(\w+)/NNP\b"

from re import findall
print(findall(tags_pattern, text))
```

Comment: Wutz, This worked great. I used your code to access a text file. Is there any way you can explain the RE to me? My file has XML like tags and everytime I find a match with the code above I want to go back towards the beginning of the file until I find that XML tag and out put it with the match. Is there a way to do this with the code above? Thanks again for you help with this I have never used RE before.